# For a Kotlin function used as an expression, is there concise way to operate on and return a value?

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

In Kotlin the final statement of a function can be interpreted as its return value.

Can a situation like the following example be simplified to be less verbose?

```
{ text: String ->
  val validated = validateText(text)
  if (validated) {
    actOnValidation()
  }
  validated
}
```

A concrete case where I would like to do this is below in an example using RxJava - even if there's a better Rx approach I'm also interested in a pure Kotlin solution if it exists.

```
fun inputChainObservable(targetField: TextView, chainedField: TextView): Observable<Boolean> {
  return targetField.textChanges()
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .map { cs: CharSequence? ->
        val hasInput = validateText(cs.toString())
        if (hasInput) {
          chainedField.requestFocus()
        }
        hasInput
      }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `also()` to operate on and return the receiver:

```
{ text: String ->
    validateText(text).also { valid ->
        if (valid) actOnValidation()
    }
}
```

You can also write it like this, but I prefer the first form because I think it's clearer:

```
{ text: String ->
    validateText(text).also {
        if (it) actOnValidation()
    }
}
```